# Catch any error, specially unexpectedly found nil in swift

Tags: swift

How can I catch any error, and I mean any type, including fatal errors, exceptions, any type...
in other languages we would use try, catch, but the do, catch doesn't do the trick when it's wrapping nil values. but why? really why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a do-catch statement to handle errors by running a block of code. If an error is thrown by the code in the do clause, it is matched against the catch clauses to determine which one of them can handle the error.

You use try? to handle an error by converting it to an optional value. If an error is thrown while evaluating the try? expression, the value of the expression is nil. For example, in the following code x and y have the same value and behavior:

```
func someThrowingFunction() throws -> Int {
    // ...
}

let myValue1 = try? someThrowingFunction()

let myValue2: Int?
do {
    myValue2 = try someThrowingFunction()
} catch {
    myValue2 = nil
}
```

If someThrowingFunction() throws an error, the value of myValue1 and myValue2 is nil. Otherwise, the value of myValue1 and myValue2 is the value that the function returned. Note that myValue1 and myValue2 are an optional of whatever type someThrowingFunction() returns. Here the function returns an integer, so myValue1 and myValue2 are optional integers.

Using try? lets you write concise error handling code when you want to handle all errors in the same way. For example, the following code uses several approaches to fetch data, or returns nil if all of the approaches fail

```
func fetchData() -> Data? {
    if let data = try? fetchDataFromDisk() { return data }
    if let data = try? fetchDataFromServer() { return data }
 return nil
}
```

if you want to check nil value , you can also use like this :-

```
var myValue: Int?


if let checkValue:Int = myValue {
  // run this when checkValue has a value which is not ni
}
```

Comment: fine, but wouldn't it make more sense to just throw and exception when unwrapping nil values? what are the advantages to this type of error handling? you just have to write way more code to check for stuff.

Comment: Yeah for unwrapping nil values just use if let, as i mentioned in last :). I used do catch only on network handling. :).

Answer (score 15):

If I need to unwrap many optional values, for example when working with collections of `Any` values, it's not conveniently to write multiple `guard let` or `if let` statements. Instead, I'm using `do-try-catch` to handle `nil`. To achieve this, I'm using this simple `unwrap` snippet:

```
public struct UnwrapError<T> : Error, CustomStringConvertible {
    let optional: T?

    public var description: String {
        return "Found nil while unwrapping \(String(describing: optional))!"
    }
}


func unwrap<T>(_ optional: T?) throws -> T {
    if let real = optional {
        return real
    } else {
        throw UnwrapError(optional: optional)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
do {
    isAdsEnabled = try unwrap(dictionary["isAdsEnabled"] as? Bool)
    // Unwrap other values...
} catch _ {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: If i were you, i'd copy paste this answer everywhere a "how to catch unwrapping errors ?" is asked, or at least give a reference to this answer.

This is the real answer to the original quesiton.

Comment: Great answer! Exactly the answer to the question

Comment: @TheFuquan, I posted it in my blog: https://kelindev.blogspot.com/2018/01/catching-nil-as-error.html

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, that doesn't exist in swift.

You can catch errors that are thrown by a function like this:

```
do {
   let outcome = try myThrowingFunction()
} catch Error.SomeError {
   //do stuff
} catch {
  // other errors
}
```

or ignore thrown errors and just continue like this:

```
let outcome = try? myThrowingFunction()
```

but catching an unforeseen crash is not possible

Comment: OK, but that should be possible right? I mean it's an expected, necessary feature of ANY language to have this shit? right? otherwise how the heck am I supposed to get these errors?

Comment: Yes, it should. Yes, it is. You are supposed, by using `if let`, `guard` and several other techniques, to program in a defensive way, a way in which crashes cannot occur (obviously this will never really happen in real world, only in a happy world without war, violence, money or [lawyers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2VxpTMAbas))